# LibGDX setScreen() crashes game when done multiple times

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a `GameScreen` and after end of the level I set the screen back to `GameScreen` as a **restart** when user taps restart button. I do this `this.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));` and before I do that line of code I dispose the screen itself, all the textures used in screen, font files and so on, everything except box2D (world because disposing it gives me native error and makes the game crash ). But even though I dispose assets before I set screen game still crashes after 15-20 restarts.

I have analyzed the memory usage by printing JavaHeap, and found out that the momory usage increases in every restart until certain point and then gets back to low point like this:

```
- Restart1: 10MB
- Restart2: 13MB
- Restart3: 15MB
- Restart4: 10MB
- Restart5: 11MB
- Restart6: 14MB
- Restart7: 9MB
```

I have read about memory usage and found out that this kind of behavior is normal. But still my game crashes after few restarts without even giving error message.

What could be causing this?

EDIT: I tested the game on ZTE Blade and found out that the game gets slower by every reset, but still crashes in around 15-20 resets.

Answer (score 1):

The memory up and down pattern is standard for garbage collection, you only have to worry if it starts being unable to reach the previous low point after a garbage collection as that would indicate a memory leak. It sounds like there might be something you aren't disposing of but why are you disposing anything if you are just going to reload all the same assets?

Switch to using the `AssetManager`. If you call `AssetManager.load` in your `Screen` constructor, `AssetManager.finishLoading` in your `Screen.show` method and `AssetManager.unload` in your `Screen.hide` method you should never unload any of your `GameScreen` assets because of how `AssetManager` does reference counting and you would only unload those assets if you navigated to a different screen. Don't forget to call `` `AssetManager.update `` in your `render` method.

Comment: I have analyzed it and there is no leaks. around 15-20run memory usage is same as it was in the beginning. Do I really need to use AssetManager if I only have 4-6 sprites in whole game and 1 font file?

Comment: No you don't have to but there really isn't any reason not to. Why don't you start by figuring out if the problem is related to your assets...load them in your `Game.create` method pass them into your `GameScreen` (maybe some static variables for now) and then only dispose in `Game.dispose`.

Comment: But I don't get any kind of error, the game just crashes without any notice. How am I supposed to debug to see if its assets related?

Comment: Maybe by attempting to do what I'm telling you? You basically said it crashes when you recreate your screen and dispose/reload your assets over and over so maybe the first step is to stop reloading the same assets over and over again when you don't need to. If that doesn't fix it then you know you have a different problem.

And you really have no debug/log output? Which backend are you using desktop, android, etc? What is your log level?

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna go ahead and try to implemet it so that I dont need disposing. I am using eclipse and LogCat. I use android and desktop

Answer (score 0):

You probably have solved your problem somehow since it has been almost a year but I will just put this here anyway, hopefully it may help people who are looking for solutions to this kind of errors.

I have a similar mechanism for one of my applications and I experienced a native crash with Box2d world too. It was when I used setScreen(new GameScreen(game)) after disposing the original one.

I used to have the following kind of initialization:

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {
/*Global Variables*/
... 
final private static World world = new World(new Vector2(0, 0), true);  //Create a world with no gravity;
...
public GameScreen(SGM game){...}
```

It turned out that I have to initialize world in the constructor. Now I have the following working without any crash no matter how many times I dispose and recreate it:

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {
/*Global Variables*/
... 
final private static World world;
...
public MatchScreen(SGM game){
this.game = game;
world = new World(new Vector2(0, 0), true);   //Create a world with no gravity
```

I'm not sure if that was also the cause in your case but well, it's just another suggestion.